# C algorithm to avoid overflow of pow and mod during RSA

Tags: c, encryption, integer-overflow

I am doing RSA encryption and decryption, and ran into the problem of overflow when I try to `pow(ascii, e) % c`.

I tried another approach, which is multiplying `ascii` by itself `e` times, and `mod c` each time. This should give me something an `int` or a `long` can hold. However, I am not getting the correct encrypted numbers.

I am trying to encrypt the string `Hello`. The expected output should be

```
1148 326 1145 1145 1780
```

But I am getting

```
1343 1450 379 379 855
```

This is what I have

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
   char buff[128];
   strncpy(buff, "Hello\n",6);

   int n = 0;
   while(buff[n] != '\n') {
      int i;
      int ascii = (int)buff[n];
      int en = ascii;

      int e = 451; // example
      int c = 2623; // example
      // instead of raising to power of e, multiply by itself e times
      // then mod c each time
      for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {
         en = (en * ascii) % c;
      }
      fprintf(stdout, "%d ", en);

      n++;
   }
   fprintf(stdout, "\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to loop `e-1` times rather than `e` times.  Note that the first loop pass would find the square.  As for the `pow()` function, you're probably best avoiding functions that use floating point types for this.

Comment: I'm concerned you're trying RSA yourself. There's too many ways to get weak keys.

Comment: I actually just started learning network programming in C so this is just something for me to get familiar with stuff.

Comment: PTN is guaranteed weak keys if they fit in anything smaller than BigInteger.  But he is also pretty much guaranteed to increase his knowledge if it's just an exercise to gain understanding.

Comment: @PTN Others already gave you a good solution to your problem, so this comment is not directly about that.  However, just to help you with your learning a bit, if you have a look at the Wikipedia page on Modular Exponentiation, you'll see that you discovered the memory efficient method they describe there.  But if you look further down, you'll see the right to left binary method.  Ignore the summation notation if you don't understand it; the pseudo code is the main thing.  If you have very large exponents, that one is good to know.  In case you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop should run for `e-1` times. because in first iteration you will get square and so on....

Answer (score 1):

int en = ascii; //a bug here, en = 1